# Width 100% is larger than the screen size

Tags: html, css

I have a div which is directly child of the body which has "`witdh: 100%`". But it is larger than the real screen size. Of course the body and html tags have also "`width 100%`". Any idea?

Code : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lpwhgbz/)

```
<div id="main-wrapper">
    <div id="text"></div>
    <div id="controlButtons">
        <div id="left-button" class="disabled">
            <div id="triangle-left"></div>
            <button class="previous-button button">Pr&eacute;c&eacute;dent</button>
        </div>
        <div id="page-number-display"><span id="page-number"></span>/8</div>
        <div id="right-button">
            <button class="next-button button">Suivant</button>
            <div id="triangle-right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `#main-wrapper` - that fixes it.

`#main-wrapper` has 100% width PLUS 15px padding, which is more than 100%. `box-sizing: border-box;` includes the padding in the width.

https://jsfiddle.net/tx9wLb40/

Answer (score 2):

Change the style for your `main-wrapper` ID to:

```css
#main-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #848484;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, it's the box model pushing the width beyond the declared width. Instead of using `width: 100%`, since your element is absolutely positioned, you can use `left: 0; right: 0;` and the item will span 100% width responsively without having to declare a width or your padding pushing the box model beyond 100%.

```css
html,
body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

html {
 background-color: #1C1C1C;
}
body {
 font-family: "Arial";
 -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
     -ms-user-select: none;
         user-select: none;
}

#controlButtons {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
}

.button {
 height: 35px;
 width: 85px;
 background-color: #1C1C1C;
 font-weight: 600;
 color: lightgrey;
 border:none;
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: none;
}

.next-button {
 border-top-left-radius: 5px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.previous-button {
 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; 
}
#triangle-right {
 position: relative;
 left: -3px;
 top: 0.45px;
 background-color: #1C1C1C;
 text-align: left;
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#triangle-right:before,
#triangle-right:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 background-color: inherit;
}

#triangle-right,
#triangle-right:before,
#triangle-right:after {
 width: 1.178em;
 height: 1.178em;
 border-top-right-radius: 20%;
}

#triangle-right {
 transform: rotate(-90deg) skewX(-30deg) scale(1,.866);
}

#triangle-right:before {
 transform: rotate(-135deg) skewX(-45deg) scale(1.414,.707) translate(0,-50%);
}

#triangle-right:after {
 transform: rotate(135deg) skewY(-45deg) scale(.707,1.414) translate(50%);
}

#triangle-left {
 position: relative;
 right: -3px;
 top: 0.45px;
 background-color: #1C1C1C;
 text-align: left;
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#triangle-left:before,
#triangle-left:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 background-color: inherit;
}

#triangle-left,
#triangle-left:before,
#triangle-left:after {
 width: 1.178em;
 height: 1.178em;
 border-top-right-radius: 20%;
}

#triangle-left {
 transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(-30deg) scale(1,.866);
}

#triangle-left:before {
 transform: rotate(-135deg) skewX(-45deg) scale(1.414,.707) translate(0,-50%);
}

#triangle-left:after {
 transform: rotate(135deg) skewY(-45deg) scale(.707,1.414) translate(50%);
}

#main-wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 top: 150px;
 left: 0;
  right: 0;
 background-color: #848484;
 padding: 15px;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

.disabled {
 opacity: 0.2;
}

.disabled:hover {
 background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<body>
  <div id="main-wrapper">
   <div id="text"></div>
   <div id="controlButtons">
    <div id="left-button" class="disabled">
     <div id="triangle-left"></div><button class="previous-button button">Pr&eacute;c&eacute;dent</button>
    </div>
    <div id="page-number-display"><span id="page-number"></span>/8</div>
    <div id="right-button">
     <button class="next-button button">Suivant</button><div id="triangle-right"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem occurs because your browser, by default, doesn't take into account values of `border` and `padding` when calculating the `width`. So it renders it as the value you've given, `100%`, plus any `padding` and `border` values.

To fix this, add `box-sizing: border-box` to `#main-wrapper`. This will ensure that `padding` and `border` values will be included when calculating `width`